# RESTEasy: How to fall back to other matching resource methods?

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

In a RESTEasy application I need to determine at runtime if a certain path can be handled by a specific resource method, based on it's path/query parameters. If it can't be handled I want the request to fallback to other methods. E.g.:

```
@Path("/")
class MyResource {
    @GET
    @Path("{path : .*}")
    public Response handleRedirects(@PathParam("path") String path) {
        if (hasRedirectFor(path)) {
            return redirectTo(path);
        }
        else {
            //somehow pretend that this method didn't exist and fallback to the next best match
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("img/{image}")
    public Response handleImage(@PathParam("image") String someParam) {
        return createImageResponse(image);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{template : .*\\.html}")
    public Response handleTemplate(@PathParam("template") String template) {
        return createTemplateResponse(template);
    }
}
```

Is this somehow possible, without having to use a `RequestFilter`? (I don't want to use a `RequestFilter` since then I need to implement URL matching for `handleSometimes` myself).

EDIT: The comments requested to provide more details, so I changed the example to match closer to my real world situation. I have a typical webserver that handles all sorts of requests, in the above example I reduced that to just images and templates. For legacy reasons there are some incoming links from 3rd parties to URLs that don't (or no longer) exists, but which we don't want to break. We therefore want to serve redirects on those URLs, which is what the `handleRedirects` function is supposed to do.

Unfortunately there is overlap in the patterns for legacy and supported urls, which prevents me from writing `@Path` annotations to statically route to the correct method. Moreover, I only know if I can actually generate a redirect from legacy -> new when I examine the path at runtime, if this fails I want to fall back to the other methods. I therefore want to be able to determine in the method itself whether I can handle the request or not, and let RESTEasy fallback to the next matching resource if it can't. Usually this is something were filters would come in handy, but then I loose the ability to automatically extract path parameters or to route to different methods, which I really like to keep.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve. Could you please add more details?

Comment: I updated my example & added more explanation, I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: As I can see, you've already gave up on filters. But I'm just wondering I you have ever considered a [pre-matching filter](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9827). Couldn't it do the trick? In a pre-matching filter, you can even change the requested URI.

Comment: Pre-matching filters do the job, but those are really a last resort. In reality I don't have just one `handleRedirects` method, but a bunch of different methods that all do a specific type of redirect. Most of these methods also need to extract some query/path parameters from the URL. If I use a filter than I need to implement my own routing & parameter extraction. I much rather use JAX-RS annotations to do that for me.

Comment: Another possible solution could be [`ResourceContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceContext.html). Have a look [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jaxrs20-1929352.html) for further details.